# Delete cached file for a specific URI

Tags: php, caching, symfony, symfony-2.1

When I use HTTP cache for a custom page, Symfony2 creates a file for it under the cache folder and it's possible to set timeout for this cache. But when I update some of my database information that is related to that particular page my users are unable to see changes (depending on the cache life time). In order to solve this problem I want to delete a specific file in update action with the URI of that page but I don't know how to do it!.

Do you know how to delete a cached file with its URI or any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Read it http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html

Comment: In symfony book said:"The most standard way is to purge the cache for a given URL by requesting it with the special
PURGE HTTP method". but how can I create a PURGE HTTP method from inside of my symfony controller?

Answer (score 1):

For me works this, but I have modified my Enviroment Class. You have to use your own Cache-Path and Enviroment:

```
private function clearCache($slug)
{
    global $kernel;
    if (get_class($kernel) == 'AppCache') {
        $key = 'md' . hash('sha256', ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? 'http://' : 'https://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $slug);
        $cacheMdFileName = \Environment::instance()->getCachePath() . '/' . $kernel->getKernel()->getEnvironment() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'http_cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 0, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 2, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 4, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 6);
        $file = file_get_contents($cacheMdFileName);
        $key = unserialize($file)[0][1]['x-content-digest'][0];
        $cacheEnFileName = \Environment::instance()->getCachePath() . '/' . $kernel->getKernel()->getEnvironment() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'http_cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 0, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 2, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 4, 2) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 6);

        unlink($cacheMdFileName);
        unlink($cacheEnFileName);
    }
}
```